# How to extract other sysmbols from PDF file in scala

Tags: scala, pdf, pdfbox

Given: A PDF file, I want to extract symbols from that pdf file.

Tried:

```
val foldedFlow = Flow[ByteString].fold(ByteString()) {
  case (bs, element) => bs ++ element
}
val logFlow = Flow.fromFunction { bytes: ByteString =>
  logger.info("Received test bytes: " + bytes.length)
  bytes
}

     val result: ByteString = Await.result(response.entity.dataBytes
          .via(logFlow)
          .via(foldedFlow)
          .runWith(Sink.head[ByteString])(client.materializer),
          10.seconds)
    
        val pdf = PDDocument.load(result.toArray[Byte])
        val stripper = new PDFTextStripper
        val contents = stripper.getText(pdf)
        pdf.close()
        contents
```

Input:

```
 私は素晴らしいよ原因こんにちは、これは日本語のテキストの例は、正しくレンダリ
ングです!
S0001 HEADACHE Mar 22, 2014
S0008 NAUSEA May 18, 2014
S0011 STOMACACHE Feb 12, 2008
S0001 HEADACHE Mar 22, 2014
S0008 NAUSEA May 18, 2014
S0011 STOMACACHE Feb 12, 2008
```

Output:

```
S0001 HEADACHE Mar 22, 2014
S0008 NAUSEA May 18, 2014
S0011 STOMACACHE Feb 12, 2008
S0001 HEADACHE Mar 22, 2014
S0008 NAUSEA May 18, 2014
S0011 STOMACACHE Feb 12, 2008
```

> pdftextstripper is not able to extract " 私は素晴らしいよ原因こんにちは、これは日本語のテキストの例は、正しくレン" this from the file
> how to solve this suggest some

Comment: Most likely some information required for text extraction are incorrect or missing in your document. Please share it for analysis.

Comment: i have edited the code, i tried to give best info i could

Comment: Please share the PDF and tell what version you are using.

Comment: pdfbox= 2.0.4. the text inside pdf i have given in the above.

Comment: The problem is not the plain *text inside pdf* but details on how it's drawn. So if you want a more well-founded analysis, please share the pdf. Otherwise see my first comment: Most likely some information required for text extraction are incorrect or missing in your document.

Comment: https://spaces.hightail.com/space/9Dv5As23nl
here is the link of pdf. only the above symbol I showed is missing. bt that symbols is Japanese language. i was not able to generate that in the pdf. so, help how to put the write code. what are the more settings will be required.

Comment: The PDF you shared does not have japanese symbols. And 2.0.4 is 4 years old, why would you use such an old version? The current version is 2.0.21. And your comment is about "generate that in the pdf", your question is about "extracting from a pdf" - which one is it?

Comment: that is i said, i tried to put the japense symbols in the pdf but it does not generated with that symbols.  so, i tried to do with manual pdf where i put the japanse symbols, den tried to extract those japanse symbols . then also i am not able to extract. i hope u r clear now. my main concern is to extract Japanese symbols and also to generate a pdf with japanse symbols. can u help with this?

Comment: So this is two different questions. The extract question can't be answered if you don't have a PDF with these symbols. It's like asking "I can't find the handbrake in my car" but you don't have a car. The create PDF is not there as a question at all. Please create a new question with that and show the code that you used.

Comment: https://spaces.hightail.com/space/9Dv5As23nl, here is the pdf. in which I am trying to extract those japanse symbols.

Comment: The "IPAPGothic" font has an incorrect /ToUnicode table, i.e. the wrong unicode values for the glyphs. One can see this by opening the PDF in PDFDebugger, and then go to "Root/Pages/Kids/[0]/Resources/XObject/Xi0/Resources/Font/f-2-1". How did you put these glyphs there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221798/discussion-between-varsha-and-tilman-hausherr).